# Jquery timestamp gets wrong year

Tags: javascript, date

Strange, but date from timestamp

```
timestamp=20141021102933;
date=new Date(timestamp);
```

returns 2608 year 30 March however it is 2014 year 21 of october(today date). What's the problem?

Comment: That's not a valid format for the a Date constructor, its being interpreted as unix epoch time which it clearly is not.  Convert to a string and use the `(yyyy, mm, dd, ...)` constructor.

Comment: Its not a valid timestamp, its just a merged form of date. For more info about timestamp http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_timestamp.asp

Comment: I get date in that format. I can't use normal method. Should I split it in array or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)` constructor;

```
var s = "20141021102933"

var d = new Date(s.substr(0, 4), 
                 +s.substr(4, 2) - 1,
                 s.substr(6, 2), 
                 s.substr(8, 2), 
                 s.substr(10, 2), 
                 s.substr(12, 2), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the individual date parameters to `Date()`:

```
var date = new Date(2014, 10, 21, 10, 29, 33);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvb3k0az/)